# Why should I switch to CodeRush from ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, coderush

For a long time I have been working with ReSharper.

But after seeing CodeRush being used in a tutorial video, I started to wonder if I should consider to try CodeRush as well.

But before giving a try I wanted to ask you if you've had a chance to work both with ReSharper and CodeRush, so that you could share your **objective** opinions on their advantages and disadvantages over each other.

Comment: @Justin: Thanks for stressing the keyword 'objective.' I think that is quite important.

Comment: Curious, if I may ask, what video was that?

Comment: @Hadi Hariri: NHibernate tutorials.'Summer of NHibernate Screencast Series'

Comment: @burak, you are welcome.  I say CodeRush used in those tutorials too.  It looked really powerful and handy.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I was mostly curious because the same can be accomplished with ReSharper so wondering how we could make that more obivous.

Comment: I know you have stated that you are a long time user of ReSharper but are you using it to its full potential? As a long time user of ReSharper myself I know I find a new feature from time to time I wasn't aware of. see http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download a demo of CR and give it a shot.

If you've already spent good money on RS, think about the ROI and the (possible) learning curve for CR, although the learning curve should be sorted out during the evaluation :-). The company where I am is using the Developer Express suite of products (which include CR) and I am loving it. I find it very productive and useful.

Disclaimer: I am a DevExpress "fanboi."

Comment: I would add that this learning curve can be significantly reduced through the use of this CodeRush plugin -> http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/CR_ReSharperCompatibility